# How to remove transparency for an UIView in iOS 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiview

I have got a complex situation. PFB code

```
UIView *whiteView ;
whiteView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor] ;
whiteView.alpha = 1.0 ;
UIView *blackView ;
blackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor] ;
blackView.alpha = 0.6 ;
blackView.frame = self.view.frame ;
[blackView addSubview:whiteView] ;
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor] ;
[self.view addSubview:blackView] ;
```

now, If I run the application, whiteView is not showing pure white. but its showing transparent white color with blue color mix.

How to make this view to pure white color ?

I have tried adding an image to the whiteView. No use.

Comment: the white view's alpha will be calculated via a simple multiplication from its superview's alphas: `1.0 * 0.6 = 0.6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

whiteView is transparent because it is inside blackView (where you have set the alpha to 0.6), this means that any subviews are also transparent as well.

Try moving whiteView out of blackView (but add it to self.view after you added blackView, that way it will be on top)

Answer (score 0):

Because you add whiteview as a subview of blackview also you set alpha of blackview.
because black view is the superclass of whiteview so it's alpha label is same like whiteview.
You can do this like interchange the whiteview and blackview. make blackview to subview of whiteview and then subview the whiteview to self.view